# Refactor both sync and async method implementations

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, refactoring, abstract

Let's say we have an abstract class which has an abstract method that can be use both in sync and async variants.

```js
abstract class Base
{
    abstract do(): number | Promise<number>;
}
```

Now I create two children of this class for sync and async usage:

```js
class SyncBase extends Base
{
    do(): number
    {
        console.log('Start');

        /* Sync-class specific code */
        let result = 5;

        console.log('End');

        return result;
    }
}

class AsyncBase extends Base
{
    async do()
    {
        console.log('Start');

        /* Async-class specific code */
        let result = await /* ... */;

        console.log('End');

        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I repeat the code before and after class specific code.

Is there a way to refactor this code so I only write before-after code once and not repeat myself?

Answer (score 0):

The abstract should be the logic for the result of `do` function. And `do` function will handle your duplicated logic:

```
abstract class Base {
    do(): number | Promise<number> {
        console.log('Start');

        const result = this.getResult(); // call abstract function

        console.log('End');

        return result;
    };

    abstract getResult(): number | Promise<number>;
}

// Then
class SyncBase extends Base {
    getResult(): number {
        const result = 5;
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}


class AsyncBase extends Base {
    async getResult()
    {
        const result = await Promise.resolve(5);
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

My recommendation: Don't mix sync and async return type (`number | Promise<number>`), just return `Promise<number>` and `getResult` and `do` will be `async` function always.